# How to create bootable USB in Linux without root access?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub

My laptop HD died (continuously getting grub-rescue screen with attempt to read or write outside hd0 error), now I dont have a bootable CD/USB and all PCs at my workplace have non-root access (so cannot use dd,unetbootin methods)

Is there any alternative to creating an installation USB ? Will extracting an ISO image manually work ?

Comment: Theoretically you can boot from another computer on the network (keywords: PXE, TFPT). That should work but is often not a simple procedure to learn.  An other option would be to ask someone to burn that CD/USB for you or to search for the DVD/USB you used to install the OS in the first place.

Comment: Sidenote about asking someone else: As IT person at work I would not have any problem creating such a CD. Nor would any of my IT coworkers.

This is because it does not take much time. It is just a download-do job related stuff - burn - do more job related stuff - handover the CD.

I would object to actually solving it during work time. (which is the most common question I got about personal laptops during office hours.)